# Ошибка: invalid conversion 'from' int to 'int(*)[]'

Tags: c++

Не понимаю, в связи с чем появляется данная ошибка, подскажите, как ее решить.
Заранее спасибо

```
int main() 
{
const int n = 6, m = 6;
int A[n][m];
int ch;

int(*func)(int A[][m], const int, const int);

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

cout << "Доступна матрица: " << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = rand() % 2;
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << '\n' << "Выберите действие: ";
cin >> ch;

if (ch == 0)
{
    return 0;
}

else if (ch == 1)
{
    func = getColNum;
    func(A[n][m], n, m);
}
}
```

Comment: int getColNum(int A[][6], const int n, const int m)

Вот что принимает getColNum

Comment: Не `func(A[n][m], n, m);` — вы же не передаете первым *один*, да еще и несуществующий, элемент, а `func(A, n, m);`